# Are Maestro debit cards (iDEAL) accepted in Italy?

Tags: italy, payment-cards, netherlands

I am traveling from the Netherlands to Italy but I don't have credit card, only a debit card (Maestro) ING. Does it work everywhere (hotels, restaurants, trains, cafes, museums ..) or are there any restrictions?

Comment: FYI: iDEAL is the name of an online payment system. It's not related to the Maesto brand or the card working abroad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, from my experience, all Dutch debit cards perfectly work in Italy. The only one possible exception are hotels since they quite often require credit card presence when you check in.

In any case of issues, you can go to any bank office and take cash as much you needed. And order an credit card from ING since it is handy in exceptional cases and buying online

Comment: Could you add your two comments to your answer, to round it out?  Then, you can delete the comments (answers stay, comments can disappear). Thx.

Answer (score 3):

I have a Maestro debit card issued by an Italian bank. It works without a glitch both in Italy as well as abroad. For completeness sake, note that when paying by card in Italy, the cashier will ask you whether you want to pay by credit or debit card by saying "*carta o bancomat?*". *Carta* means credit card and *bancomat* is debit card.

Comment: Historically, the `Carta o bancomat?` question comes from the choice posted by the POS device. Oldest multi-circuit cards had two modes so that `bancomat` mode required PIN authentication, while `card` mode required to sign the receipt, and then the clerk asked for the cardholder's ID. Today's chip cards, while presenting both choices for technical reasons, either require a PIN for both channels or **none**